# How to pass Attribute as dependency in provide function?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am building simple Login Verification directive, that will work as described [here](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.lojo85v8j). I would like to make some adjustments - I would like to create new Provider in boot function like this:

```
new Provider(RouterOutlet, {
    useFactory: (_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader:DynamicComponentLoader, _parentRouter: Router,_authenticationService:AuthenticationService) => new SessionVerificationRouterOutlet(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, _authenticationService),
    deps: [ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader, Router, AuthenticationService]
})
```

However, as you can see here:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'auth-router-outlet'
})
export class SessionVerificationRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    publicRoutes: string[];
    private parentRouter: Router;


    constructor(
        _elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
        _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,  private _authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

        this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
        this._authenticationService = _authenticationService;
        this.publicRoutes = [
            'login'
        ];
    }

    activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
        if (this._canActivate(instruction.urlPath)) {
            return super.activate(instruction);
        }

        this.parentRouter.navigate(['Login']);
    }

    _canActivate(url) {
        return this.publicRoutes.indexOf(url) !== -1 || this._authenticationService.isLoggedIn()
    }
}
```

As we can see, 'SessionVerificationRouterOutlet' take also `@Attribute` element in the constructor. How can I pass the required attribute in  the `new Provider(..)` method?

Comment: I'm sure this is not possible when you use `useFactory` to instantiate the router-outlet. Why do you use `useFactory`?

Answer (score 1):

`@Attribute` will get the value as a constant from an attribute of the element (in your case, the `name` one) where the directive applies on. Somethinhg like that:

```
<auth-router-outlet name="something"></auth-router-outlet>
```

There is no need to define when create the provider... Moreover I don't think that you need to use `useFactory` to configure your custom router outlet. The following would be enough:

```
provide(RouterOutlet, {
  useClass: SessionVerificationRouterOutlet
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**update**

To use a custom `<router-outlet>` just list it in the directives array of your component:

```
@Component({
  ...
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SessionVerificationRouterOutlet],
})
```

Ensure it is listed after `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

To provide it globally use

```
provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SessionVerificationRouterOutlet], multi: true})
```

**original**

This should do as well:

```
provide(RouterOutlet, {useClass: SessionVerificationRouterOutlet}),
```

then the `@Attribute()` should work.

Otherwise you can just use a `@Input()`

```
export class SessionVerificationRouterOutlet {
  @Input() name:String;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

The value won't be available in the constructor though, only when the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle callback was called.

Comment: Actually, for some reason, the directive is not called. I will create plnkr in a sec.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to provide it at all. Just add it to the `directives: [...]` array. Ensure you list it after `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` if you have them there as well.

Comment: I've tried your answer - but I think there is some conflicts between the two classes we provide: I receive the '`Primary outlet is already registered.`', when I just added the `provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SessionVerificationRouterOutlet], multi: true})`

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: Its beta 15. I've got passed the issue I was mentioning in previous comment, but since I am using ng2-translate, I got this error described here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6425

Comment: I saw your above error message `Primary outlet is already registered.` related to minification which was fixed in beta.16 IIRC.

Comment: I will upgrade to the latest version soon, so I will keep you updated.